# X is not a function in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my App.js component I have this state :
`const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');`

I have passed this into the Search component as a prop to update the text that I write in the search bar that I have created in the search component.

```
This is the error that is coming : bundle.js:461 Uncaught TypeError: props.handleSearchNote is not a function
```

Here is how i have passed in the function in App.js:

And this is my search component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { MdSearch } from 'react-icons/md'

const Search = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='search'>
            <MdSearch className='search-icons' size='1.3em' />
            <input
                onChange={(event) =>
                    props.handleSearchNote(event.target.value)
                }
                type='text'
                placeholder='type to search...'
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Search;
```

This is where I have passed the Search component in App.js

```
 return (
    <>

      <div className='container'>
        <Search handlSearchNote={setSearchText} />
        {console.log(searchText)}
        <NotesList
          notes={notes.filter((note) => note.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchText))}
          handleAddNote={addNote}
          handleDeleteNote={deleted} />
      </div>
    </>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: where do you call the Search component

Comment: The App.js snippet is missing

Comment: Error says that either `handleSearchNote` is not passed to `Search` component or `handleSearchNote` is passed but it's type is not a function. So, in the first place you should explore the parent component of `Search` where you passed `handleSearchNote` as a prop to `Search`.

Comment: I have updated the code and put in the app.js code snippet. I cannot find out the error in the App .Js component where i have called the Search component and passed setSearchText as a prop.

Comment: Where is the logic for `setSearchText` in your component?

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning setSearchText to handlSearchNote not handleSearchNote. You forgot the 'e' in handle. This happens to me all the time.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. These silly errors, ugh. Wasted so much time figuring out the bug. Small spelling mistakes and case mistakes are part and parcel of React tbh . Thanks for reading through such a long code to find out this silly a bug.

Comment: It's alright